# How do I set up visual studio to work with .net 3.5 CF?

Tags: wcf, compact-framework, windows-mobile-5.0

I'm trying to build a Windows Mobile 5 WCF client. This project currently uses web services but I'd like to convert it to WCF. I installed the .NET CF 3.5 redistributable on the device, but how do I get the "Add Service Reference" menu option to show up on my existing project in VS 2008?

Comment: Take a look at [this article on WCF for Device Developers](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/archives/An%20introduction%20to%20wcf%20for%20device%20developers.pdf).

Comment: Do you have VS 2008 SP1 installed? there were some CF dev setup issues that were rectified as a result.

Comment: the link is not found. May I get any more?

Comment: Link has been updated

Answer (score 1):

Just realized I used my wrong reply (yes I have a collection of these for work)

anyhow, google 'NetCFSvcUtil' if you are running windows 7 then you need the newer version - [Updated NetCFSvcUtil](http://blogs.msdn.com/habibh/archive/2009/06/26/netcfsvcutil-exe-and-windows-7.aspx)

Basically you are going to use this utility to crate a proxy for you.

---

Rather long winded post but this will get you started :)

Google these things then, download and install :

Running Vista or greater ?  : Windows Mobile Device Center 6.1 Driver for Windows Vista 
Otherwise : Active Sync (methinks the latest verson is 4.5)

Windows Mobile SDK's
- Windows Mobile 6 Standard SDK Refresh
- Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK Refresh

Windows Mobile Emulator Images
- Windows Mobile 6.1 Standard Images (USA)
- Windows Mobile 6.1 Professional Images (USA)

Configure Active Sync (WMDC)
Start Windows Mobile Device Center
Hover ‘Mobile Device Settings’ -> Select ‘Connection Settings’
Set following options :
- Allow USB Connections : true
- Allow Connections to one of the following : DMA
- This Computer connects to : Automatic
- Allow Automattic Device Authentication : true
- Allow data connections on this device when connected to the pc : true

Configure Emulator
Start Visual Studio Device Manager (create a shortcut from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Device Emulator\1.0\dvcemumanager.exe)
Right Click on an entry and press ‘Connect’ to start the emulator image
Once the Emulator has started, Right Click on the same emulator image and press ‘Cradle’ (this establishes the active sync partnership). If this is the first time you have partnered this particular emulator image WMDC will prompt for you to setup a partnership, you need to do this. You don’t need to synchronize anything (in fact I recommend you don’t) but you still need to go through the process.

Setup Network Access
Start \ Settings \ [Connections] \ Connections \ [Advanced] \ Select Networks
Both options should be set to be ‘My ISP’

Create a Device Project
Start Visual Studio
File \ New \ Project : Smart Device \ Smart Device Project - follow the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Your project is probably targeting framework 2.0.

Have your project target .NET 3.0 or 3.5 to have the "Add Service Reference" option added.

Comment: that doesn't appear to be in the properties page of a device project. I tried selecting the upgrade option from the menu but that doesn't appear to have fixed it.